# AWS Opsworks, Spring mvc: Unable to open my application on browser

Tags: aws-opsworks

I have deployed my application using AWS Opsworks. I could see that my application has been deployed successfully, however I am not able to open it in a browser. I tried many many combinations of url, but no luck.

On my localhost, I access my application with this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/login.
```

In opsworks my app name is "bootshop" and it has been deployed successfully.
Now how do i access my login page ???

I tried below urls:

```
login page:      http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/bootshop/app/login - 404 Requested resource not available

index.html page: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/bootshop/app/      - 404 Requested resource not available

             http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/bootshop/login     - 404 Requested resource not available

             http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/bootshop/           - Nothing is displayed on 

             http://xx.xx.xx.xx                - Forbidden
```

For my EC2 instance, I have custom TCP rule set.. which allows traffic on port 8080 from anywhere. 
Your help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: are you able to login to the system via SSH and actually view something on port 8080 ?

Comment: Hi, Ahmed.. when i uploaded created war file and deployed it worked. But still I don't understand why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

The 8080 address is the internal address that Apache web server uses to communicate with the Tomcat instance. The public address that you should use is 80. Just use the root path of your server to access the application, like this:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx
```

where xx.xx.xx.xx is your IP address. You can of course use the DNS name if you have any for that IP address.

Make sure that you allow HTTP traffic to port 80 in the security group for the EC2 instance where the application is running.